# Rails : simple_for_for time with 12 hour format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Is there a proper way to show 12-hour time in Rail's simple_for_for? I am currently using

```
<%= f.input :time, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 5 %>
```

however it only displays two drop downs, with the times displayed as  **01AM** in the first dropdown and **00** in the second.

I would like it to have three drop downs, for hours, minutes, and am/pm.

Comment: have you tried something like: `<%= f.input :time_field, as: :time, html5: true %>`

Comment: That got me the format that I was looking for however there are no longer drop downs. Any idea of how to get them back?

Comment: I am afraid that can not be achieved through it but you can always create  custom drop downs for the same purpose using rails form helper.

Comment: Also, selecting time through three different drop downs are more painful and probably not good for user experience. #advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#html-5-notice)

> HTML 5 date / time inputs are not generated by Simple Form by default, so using date, time or datetime will all generate select boxes using normal Rails helpers. We believe browsers are not totally ready for these yet, but you can easily opt-in on a per-input basis by passing the html5 option:

```
<%= f.input :time, as: :time, html5: true %>
```

This should fix your problem.